# How much time of life has an sd card with Raspbian Linux for ARM (Plate Raspberry Pi)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, lifetime, debian-based

Staff, this question is for anyone who believes in Debian linux, more precisely of Raspbian, which is a version to run on the board Raspberry Pi:

As all users of Raspberry Pi should know: The operating system is installed on an SD card. AND the problem is that the SD card is a Flash memory, and this type of memory supports only a limited quantity of write operations.

I would like to know if the Raspbian writes the SD card when it is idle. If this happens, how can I disable?

I found this:

> Tips for running Linux on a flash device by David Härdeman
>
> If you are running your NSLU2 on a USB flash key, there are a number
>   of things you might want to do in order to reduce the wear and tear on
>   the underlying flash device (as it only supports a limited number of
>   writes).
>
> Note: this document currently describes Debian etch (4.0) and needs to
>   be updated to Debian squeeze (6.0) and Debian wheezy (7.0). Some of
>   the hints may still apply, but some may not.
>
> The ext3 filesystem per default writes metadata changes every five
>   seconds to disk. This can be increased by mounting the root filesystem
>   with the commit=N parameter which tells the kernel to delay writes to
>   every N seconds.
>
> The kernel writes a new atime for each file that has been read which
>   generates one write for each read. This can be disabled by mounting
>   the filesystem with the noatime option.
>       Both of the above can be done by adding e.g. noatime,commit=120,... to /etc/fstab. This can also be done on an
>   already mounted filesystem by running the command:
>
> mount -o remount,noatime,commit=120 /
>
> The system will run updatedb every day which creates a database of all
>   files on the system for use with the locate command. This will also
>   put some stress on the filesystem, so you might want to disable it by
>   adding
>
> exit 0
>
> early in the /etc/cron.daily/find script.
>
> syslogd will in the default installation sync a lot of log files to
>   disk directly after logging some new information. You might want to
>   change /etc/syslog.conf so that every filename starts with a - (minus)
>   which means that writes are not synced immediately (which increases
>   the risk that some log messages are lost if your system crashes). For
>   example, a line such as:
>
> kern.*                          /var/log/kern.log
>
> would be changed to:
>
> kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
>
> You also might want to disable some classes of messages altogether by
>   logging them to /dev/null instead, see syslog.conf(5) for details.
>
> In addition, syslogd likes to write -- MARK -- lines to log files
>   every 20 minutes to show that syslog is still running. This can be
>   disabled by changing SYSLOGD in /etc/default/syslogd so that it reads
>
> SYSLOGD="-m 0"
>
> After you've made any changes, you need to restart syslogd by running
>
> /etc/init.d/syslogd restart
>
> If you have a swap partition or swap file on the flash device, you
>   might want to move it to a different part of the disk every now and
>   then to make sure that different parts of the disk gets hit by the
>   frequent writes that it can generate. For a swap file this can be done
>   by creating a new swap file before you remove the old one.
>
> If you have a swap partition or swap file stored on the flash device,
>   you can make sure that it is used as little as possible by setting
>   /proc/sys/vm/swappiness to zero.
>
> The kernel also has a setting known as laptop_mode, which makes it
>   delay writes to disk (initially intended to allow laptop disks to spin
>   down while not in use, hence the name). A number of files under
>   /proc/sys/vm/ controls how this works:
>
> /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode: How many seconds after a read should a
>   writeout of changed files start (this is based on the assumption that
>   a read will cause an otherwise spun down disk to spin up again).
>
> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs: How often the kernel should
>   check if there is "dirty" (changed) data to write out to disk (in
>   centiseconds).
>
> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs: How old "dirty" data should be
>   before the kernel considers it old enough to be written to disk. It is
>   in general a good idea to set this to the same value as
>   dirty_writeback_centisecs above.
>
> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio: The maximum amount of memory (in percent) to
>   be used to store dirty data before the process that generates the data
>   will be forced to write it out. Setting this to a high value should
>   not be a problem as writeouts will also occur if the system is low on
>   memory.
>
> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio: The lower amount of memory (in
>   percent) where a writeout of dirty data to disk is allowed to stop.
>   This should be quite a bit lower than the above dirty_ratio to allow
>   the kernel to write out chunks of dirty data in one go.
>
> All of the above kernel parameters can be tuned by using a custom init
>   script, such as this example script. Store it to e.g.
>   /etc/init.d/kernel-params, make it executable with
>
> chmod a+x /etc/init.d/kernel-params
>
> and make sure it is executed by running
>
> update-rc.d kernel-params defaults
>
> Note: Most of these settings reduce the number of writes to disk by
>   increasing memory usage. This increases the risk for out of memory
>   situations (which can trigger the dreaded OOM killer in the kernel).
>   This can even happen when there is free memory available (for example
>   when the kernel needs to allocate more than one contiguous page and
>   there are only fragmented free pages available).
>
> As with any tweaks, you are advised to keep a close eye on the amount
>   of free memory and adapt the tweaks (e.g. by using less aggressive
>   caching and increasing the swappiness) depending on your workload.
>
> This article has been contributed by David Härdeman
>
> Go back to the Debian on NSLU2 page.

http://www.cyrius.com/debian/nslu2/linux-on-flash/

Someone has some more tip?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using various raspberry pi setups and haven't had SD card troubles to date (fingers crossed). That being said, there is a bit of evidence for SD card lifespan related issues

A quick google search does show a few more tips though:

1. Bigger is better - reduces the load on specific sections
2. Write to ram for temp
3. Only store the boot partition on SD card and leave the OS on USB drive

(http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/extend-life-raspberry-pis-sd-card/)

Anyway, it'll be interesting to hear from someone who has a raspberry cluster or some such on their SD card lifespans!
(https://resin.io/blog/what-would-you-do-with-a-120-raspberry-pi-cluster/)

Answer (score 0):

You can put files in tmpfs after load and write them back before shutdown using script from http://www.observium.org/wiki/Persistent_RAM_disk_RRD_storage

But it can be detrimental:
Tmpfs *will* destroy all changes on power outage, you *must* use UPS;
Raspberry Pi RAM is far from big, don't waste it.

If your pi often writes small files this can work for you